# Java redirects to login page when tries to load CSS file

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

EDIT**

I manage to get CSS loading but it redirects back to login.jsp so it loads HTML not CSS. Any idea why?
[image]

---

I was trying to add custom CSS file to my header on login.jsp page
When I run it the CSS was not running and I was given the error:

> too many redirects

I am unsure how to fix the problem.

I have tried to find a way to allow css/js/img files to be allowed but I am unfamiliar with `web.xml` file and what is best practice to validate those entries.

The error message:

> GET http://localhost:8080/AppV2/resource/css/login
>   net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

login.jsp page:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<jsp:include page="header.jsp" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resource/css/login.css">
<body>
    <%
        String login_msg = (String) request.getAttribute("error");
        if (login_msg != null)
            out.println("<font color=red size=4px>" + login_msg + "</font>");
    %>  
<div class = "container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <form action="" method="post" name="Login_Form" class="form-signin">       
            <h3 class="form-signin-heading">Welcome Back! Please Sign In</h3>
              <hr class="colorgraph"><br>

              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Username" placeholder="Username" required="" autofocus="" />
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required=""/>            

              <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"  name="Submit" value="Login" type="Submit">Login</button>            
        </form>         
    </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Login.java Servlet:

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LoginServlet() {
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Set standard HTTP/1.1 no-cache headers.
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
        // Set standard HTTP/1.0 no-cache header.
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        if ((request.getParameter("password") == "") && (request.getParameter("password") == "")) {
            request.setAttribute("error", "Invalid Username or Password");
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } else if ((request.getParameter("password") == null) && (request.getParameter("password") == null)) {
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } else {
            String psw = request.getParameter("password");
            String usr = request.getParameter("username");
            List res = userLoginUtils.logIn(usr, psw);
            Boolean debugFlag = true;
            if (res.get(0).equals("true") || debugFlag == true) {
                this.writeToSession(res.get(1), request);
            } else {
                request.setAttribute("error", "Invalid Username or Password");
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);

            }
            response.sendRedirect("index");
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, put your  tag inside your  tag (I assume your  tag is inside header.jsp?)

Then concerning the path of your file :
You can't import it the way you did.
Try the following (EL expressions are used here )

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resource/css/login.css" />
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error message. 
My CSS  is located atm in
--WebContent -- WEB-INF -- resource

Comment: EDIT : ok that was a typo

Comment: That worked now but css is not applying. The error I am getting is
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/AppV2/login".

Comment: Can you try to put your CSS folder outside the web-inf folder? Use --WebContent -- resource and paste the link I put in my response. This should work :)

Comment: Yep it loads the css but i am getting
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/AppV2/login".

Comment: edited my response. you should put your <link> tag inside your <head> tag